# Aeropress: at what stage does most of extraction happen?

Tags: aeropress, extraction

While making coffee using the Aeropress, there are a number of stages that happen in sequence. For example,

- Initial pour of small quantity of hot water
- Stirring for about 10-20 seconds
- Pouring of the rest of the hot water (till desired water ratio)
- Wait time (usually 1 minute)
- Stir again
- Invert, and press for ~30 seconds

Question: **During which of these stages does the "extraction" (from coffee to the water) happen for the most part?**

Comment: Are you asking about *the rate of extraction* or at which point the brew contains the most dissolved material? In either case, I think the answer is trivial. If it's the former then it's obviously in the beginning and if it's the latter it's at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the "extraction" happens when the coffee is in contact with the water. So from the initial point of contact in this case the bloom phase pour till all the water (with dissolved solids) is removed from contact with the grounds.

Technically speaking, The initial small quantity pour and stirring in your recipe is the bloom phase and the second pour, stir and press would be the main extraction phase. In the case of your recipe, most of your extraction would happen during the second wait phase "Wait time (usually 1 minute)", followed by the second stir phase.

The first bloom phase is usually to let the coffee expunge as much CO2 as possible that's trapped from the roasting process. The CO2, when dissolved can make the coffee more acidic/bitter, hence the blooming phase in your recipe to mitigate that. There is also some extraction during this phase but is rather dwarfed in comparison to the main extraction phase.